# how can use hash variables with rspec capybara test specification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

My spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "State Contracts page" do 
  @state_data = {
   :state_slug => 'Alabama', 
   :state_name => 'California'
  }

 before(:each) { visit state_path(:state=>"#{@state_data[:state_slug]}" )}

 it 'should have header' do
   page.should have_content("#{@state_data[:state_name]} Contracts")
 end

# show statistics specification for State Contract
 it "should have #{@state_data[:state_name]} Statistics details" do
    page.should have_content("#{@state_data[:state_name]} Statistics") 
    page.should have_content('Total Obligated Amount')
    page.should have_content('Total Transactions')
    page.should have_content('Total Contractors')
    page.should have_content('Total Contract Recipients')
    page.should have_content('Total Offers')
  end
end

# show State link  
it "should have visible #{@state_data[:state_name]} Links" do
    page.should have_content("#{@state_data[:state_name]} Links")
    assert_equal(true, find_link("Agencies in #{@state_data[:state_name]}").visible?)
    assert_equal(true, find_link("Contractors in "{@state_data[:state_name]}").visible?)
    assert_equal(true, find_link("Contracts in #{@state_data[:state_name]}").visible?)
  end
end
```

After when I run the test, I got next Error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil class for "#{@state_data[:state_name]}"
```

I think i am interpolating hash variable but now not getting right.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use instance variables in an `it` block without declaring it somewhere in a `before`. Wrap `@state_data` in your `before(:each)` block and it should work.

It would look like the following:

```
before do
  @state_data = {
    :state_slug => 'Alabama', 
    :state_name => 'California'
  }
  visit state_path(:state=>"#{@state_data[:state_slug]}"
end
```

My understanding is that using instance variables is considered an antipattern and you should consider using `let()` or `subject()` instead

Using `let()` would change this to:

```
let(:state_data) do
  { 
    :state_slug => 'Alabama', 
    :state_name => 'California'
  }
end

before { visit state_path(:state=>"#{state_data[:state_slug]}" }

it 'should have header' do
  page.should have_content("#{state_data[:state_name]} Contracts")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Local variables or instance variables defined in a `describe` block are not accessible in any contained `it` blocks.

If you want to make arbitrary variables or methods available across multiple `it` blocks, you need to use `let`, `let!` or `before`. The `let` methods let you memoize helper methods while the `before` method let's you execute arbitrary Ruby code prior to executing the `it` block. The `subject` method is also available as means of defining the `subject` helper.

Of course, you can also define methods or variables within each `it` block.